# Store full width and half width character in unique column of database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a word list stored in mysql, and the size is around 10k words. The column is marked as unique. However, I cannot insert full-width and half-width character of punctuation mark.

Here are some examples:

```
(half-width, full-width)
('?', '？')
('/', '／')
```

The purpose is that, I have many articles containing both full-width and half-width characters and want to find out if the articles contain these words. I use php to do the comparison and it can know that '?' is different than '？'. Is there any idea how to do it in mysql too? Or is there some ways so that php can make it equal?

I use utf8_unicode_ci for the database encoding, and the column is also used utf8_unicode_ci for the encoding. When I made these queries, both return the same record, '?測試'

```
SELECT word FROM word_list WHERE word='?測試'
SELECT word FROM word_list WHERE word='？測試'
```

Comment: what's the character encoding on the tables\db?

Comment: I use utf8_unicode_ci encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely explanation is a characterset translation issue; for example, the column you are storing the value to is defined as latin1 characterset.

But it's not necessarily the characterset of the column that's causing the issue. It's a characterset conversion happening somewhere.

If you aren't aware of characterset encodings, I recommend consulting the source of all knowledge: google.

I highly recommend the two top hits for this search:

```
what every programmer needs to know about character encoding
```

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: I use utf8_unicode_ui to store the word lists. It should be enough to know the half-width, full-width of question mark and slash.

Comment: Some characters are considered equivalent in terms of sorting, they are considered "equal" even if the binary representations are different. That would cause a "duplicate key" exception like you are reporting. You may need to specify a *different* collation, like a **binary** collation, to have the characters be considered "unequal".